# Build MITK tutorial errors

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, cmake, mitk

There are some errors when I build the MITK tutorial:

Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..........\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.selectionservicemitk.views\src\internal\org_mitk_example_gui_selectionservicemitk_views_Activator.cpp': No such file or directory   F:\MITK-2014.03.0-src\MITK-superbuild\MITK-build\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.selectionservicemitk.views\c1xx

Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..........\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.extensionpointdefinition\src\internal\org_mitk_example_gui_extensionpointdefinition_Activator.cpp': No such file or directory   F:\MITK-2014.03.0-src\MITK-superbuild\MITK-build\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.extensionpointdefinition\c1xx

Error   3   error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..........\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.extensionpointcontribution\src\internal\org_mitk_example_gui_extensionpointcontribution_Activator.cpp': No such file or directory   F:\MITK-2014.03.0-src\MITK-superbuild\MITK-build\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.extensionpointcontribution\c1xx

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

It seems it couldn't find the those two .cpp files while I checked
F:\MITK-2014.03.0-src\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.selectionservicemitk.views\src\internal

and

F:\MITK-2014.03.0-src\Examples\Plugins\org.mitk.example.gui.extensionpointdefinition\src\internal

both .cpp were in the file separately.

I try to include the file path in the project but it still have the same problems.

Does anyone have some ideas? thank you.

p.s. I use vs2012+cmake-gui 2.8.12.2+QT4.8

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that some file path limits in the Windows cmd shell were exceeded. There are usually limits on both the length of individual file paths and the length of the total cmd line for compiling source files.

Try to use separate source and build directories for your MITK build (I see that you are building MITK inside its own source directory) and keep the directory names short. E.g.:

```
F:\MITK-src
F:\MITK-bin
```

Usually, the MITK build system warns you about too long path names when you use CMake to configure your build directory.